# PHP - .htaccess route by article_name

Tags: php, .htaccess

at the moment I have a URL

```
http://www.xxx.com/article.php?id=1
```

I'd like to make the URL more friendly, which is fine I've set a rewrite rule that turns it into

```
http://www.xxx.com/article/id/1/
```

Although now I want to make it even more friendly by perhaps posting the article 'title' along with it, so...

```
http://www.xxx.com/article/id/1/article-name-goes-here/
```

is there an easy elegant solution to do this?

When I echo the page should I just add an extra bit into the query string `&name=article_name_here`

Answer (score 1):

The most flexible way (and the same basic method used by many frameworks) is to just rewrite all requests to a single file (in your case `article.php`), then parse the URL there. This will avoid complex `mod_rewrite` rules, where you try to map regex matched portions of the URL to a specific GET variable.

The rewrite rule could look something like this, redirecting any URL that starts with `article/` to your php script:

```
RewriteRule article/.* article.php
```

And when `article.php` is sent this request:

```
http://example.com/article/id/1/article-name-goes-here/
```

It could just explode on `/` and find the id.

```
$requestParts = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$id = $requestParts[1];
```

On a large scope, you can rewrite all requests to the entire site to `index.php`, and in a similar fashion determine not just what article to server, but what script (article/user/etc) should handle each request.

That's the basic concept of a 'Router' in many PHP frameworks. In that case, it's important to not redirect *all* requests to your routing script (since many will be for static resources like images/css/javascript). To avoid that, generally the rules redirect any request that is not a file on the server to the router script.

Here's a sample mod_Rewrite that does that, taken from the [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.quick-start.html#zend.application.quick-start.manual):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the article name as you described above and just ignore it later on when you translate the userfriendly url to a server-side url.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass on the complete URL string to PHP and filter the ID with PHP code.

*.htaccess:*

```
RewriteRule (.+?)\/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

PHP:

```
$fragments = explode('/', $_REQUEST['page']);
// then do something with $fragments
```

`$fragments` looks like this when var_dump-ed:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "article"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "id"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [3]=>
  string(25) "title-which-is-kinda-long"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I know, All sites(perhaps many of them) use ids to identify the article when they rewrite URLs (like StackOverFlow)!

you can put article title in url but there is no need to use it when you have unique ID!!!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/\?article\.php\?id=([^&]+)&name=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /article/%1/%2? [NC,R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^article/(.*?)/(.*?)/?$ /article.php?id=$1&name=$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```